# Test suite for a white-box fuzzer

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, fuzzing, automated-testing, whitebox

I have created a white-box fuzzer by extending the [Crest](http://code.google.com/p/crest).

Now, I'm looking for a test suite (a set of c programs with known vulnerabilities) to test the functionality of my tool.

where i can find such benchmarks?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Metasploitable? https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2009/03/22/vmware-virtual-pc-and-fdcc-images

Also, you could try making your own applications, they aren't difficult to make:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call_me()
{
    system("/bin/bash");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char in[20];
    setresuid(5002,5002,5002);

    strcpy(in,argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Something like the above is all it takes for application vulnerabilities.